# ISTIO Egress gateway Flow

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

I have installed ISTIO with the below configuration

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio-control-plane
spec:
  # Use the default profile as the base
  # More details at: https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/
  profile: default
  # Enable the addons that we will want to use
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
    tracing:
      enabled: true
    kiali:
      enabled: true
  values:
    global:
      # Ensure that the Istio pods are only scheduled to run on Linux nodes
      defaultNodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kiali:
      dashboard:
        auth:
          strategy: anonymous
  components:
    egressGateways:
    - name: istio-egressgateway
      enabled: true
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    outboundTrafficPolicy:
      mode: REGISTRY_ONLY
EOF
```

and have configured the Egress Gateway, Destination Rule & Virtual Service as shown below

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: akv2k8s-test
  labels:
    istio-injection: enabled
    azure-key-vault-env-injection: enabled
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: cnn
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http-port
    protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - edition.cnn.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-for-cnn
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: cnn
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-cnn-through-egress-gateway
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  gateways:
  - istio-egressgateway
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: cnn
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: edition.cnn.com
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
EOF
```

it is working perfectly fine

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.7/samples/sleep/sleep.yaml -n akv2k8s-test
export SOURCE_POD=$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n akv2k8s-test -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})
kubectl exec "$SOURCE_POD" -n akv2k8s-test -c sleep -- curl -sL -o /dev/null -D - http://edition.cnn.com/politics
kubectl logs -l istio=egressgateway -c istio-proxy -n istio-system | tail
```

[image]

however I could not understand the control flow. For example, the below diagram show the control flow of Ingress Gateway

[image]

Can you please let me know the control flow of ISTIO Egress? or What happens when the deployed application try to access the external service? Does follow the flow : POD -> Proxy -> Virtual Service -> Destination Rule -> Gateway -> External Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Your guess was right on point.

The flow is POD > envoy proxy > Gateway > Eternal Service

When traffic is being sent out from the application container, it is intercepted by envoy proxy sidecar and envoy filter is applied.

The envoy filter chain is generated from `VirtualService` and `DestinationRule` objects it can be inspected using [`istioctl proxy-config`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/#deep-dive-into-envoy-configuration) command.